# Gdal Python problem: black strips in image translation

Tags: python, gdal, scale

I have a 500 x 500 m resolution world map of clumping index data (He et al., 2012) and I am trying to do two things at the same time: 1) to isolate the variables per plant functional type following the GLC2000 land cover map with 1 x 1 km resolution, and 2) to rescale the new maps to 0.5 x 0.5 degree resolution.

But the maps are written in different formats:

1) gdalinfo MCI2_red_global_sza0_mask.img

```
Driver: ENVI/ENVI .hdr Labelled
Files: MCI2_red_global_sza0_mask.img
       MCI2_red_global_sza0_mask.img.hdr
Size is 86400, 43200
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS_1984_Sinusoidal",
    GEOGCS["GCS_sphere_modis",
        DATUM["custom",
            SPHEROID["custom",6371007.181,0.0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Sinusoidal"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",0.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]
Origin = (-20015109.353999998420477,10007554.676999999210238)
Pixel Size = (463.312716529999989,-463.312716529999989)
Metadata:
  Band_1=Mask (Reprojection (Layer_1:glc2000_v1_1.img):MCI2_red_global_sza0.img)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-20015109.354,10007554.677) (124d17'29.21"W, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-20015109.354,-10007554.677) (154d42'44.97"E, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Upper Right (20015109.354,10007554.677) (136d31'56.59"E, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right (20015109.354,-10007554.677) (141d 0'27.35"W, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Center      (   0.0000960,  -0.0000480) (  0d 0' 0.00"E,  0d 0' 0.00"S)
Band 1 Block=86400x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = Mask (Reprojection (Layer_1:glc2000_v1_1.img):MCI2_red_global_sza0.img)
```

2) gdalinfo glc2000_v1_1.img

```
Driver: HFA/Erdas Imagine Images (.img)
Files: glc2000_v1_1.img
       glc2000_v1_1.igw
       glc2000_v1_1.rrd
Size is 40320, 16353
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["BAD DATUM",
    DATUM["BAD DATUM",
        SPHEROID["WGS84",6378137,298.2570248822722]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]
Origin = (-180.004464285700010,89.995535666300043)
Pixel Size = (0.008928571400000,-0.008928571400000)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0044643,  89.9955357) (180d 0'16.07"W, 89d59'43.93"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0044643, -56.0133924) (180d 0'16.07"W, 56d 0'48.21"S)
Upper Right ( 179.9955346,  89.9955357) (179d59'43.92"E, 89d59'43.93"N)
Lower Right ( 179.9955346, -56.0133924) (179d59'43.92"E, 56d 0'48.21"S)
Center      (  -0.0044649,  16.9910716) (  0d 0'16.07"W, 16d59'27.86"N)
Band 1 Block=256x4 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Palette
  Description = Layer_1
  Min=1.000 Max=22.000 
  Minimum=1.000, Maximum=22.000, Mean=17.701, StdDev=4.927
  Overviews: 10078x4086, 5038x2042, 2518x1020, 1258x509, 628x253, 313x125, 155x61
```

So, here it's my code:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import sys
from array import array
import osgeo.osr as osr

# Enable exceptions
gdal.UseExceptions()

MODIS_Wkt='PROJCS["unnamed",GEOGCS["Unknown datum based upon the custom spheroid",DATUM["Not specified (based on custom spheroid)",SPHEROID["Custom spheroid",6371007.181,0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Sinusoidal"],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",0],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]'


"""
A class to extract and process regions from He and Chen's Global Clumping Index data
T Quaife, 2013
"""


################################# GLC Global Class (according to LCCS terminology) ##########################################
##( 01 ) Tree Cover, broadleaved, evergreen -
##                                          LCCS >15% tree cover, tree height >3m
##                                          (Examples of sub-classes at regional level* :
##                                          closed > 40% tree cove; open 15-40% tree cover)
##( 02 )Tree Cover, broadleaved, deciduous, closed 
##( 03 )Tree Cover, broadleaved, deciduous, open  -
##                                               (open 15-40% tree cover)
##( 04 )Tree Cover, needle-leaved, evergreen
##( 05 )Tree Cover, needle-leaved, deciduous
##( 06 )Tree Cover, mixed leaf type
##( 07 )Tree Cover, regularly flooded, fresh  water (& brackish)
##( 08 )Tree Cover, regularly flooded, saline water, -
##                                                 (daily variation of water level)
##( 09 )Mosaic: -
##                Tree cover / Other natural vegetation 
##( 10 )Tree Cover, burnt
##( 11 )Shrub Cover, closed-open, evergreen
##                                        (Examples of sub-classes at reg. level *: (i) sparse tree layer)
##( 12 )Shrub Cover, closed-open, deciduous 
##                                        (Examples of sub-classes at reg. level *: (i) sparse tree layer)
##( 13 )Herbaceous Cover, closed-open 
##                                        (Examples of sub-classes at regional level *:
##                                         (i) natural, (ii) pasture, (iii) sparse trees or shrubs) 
##( 14 )Sparse Herbaceous or sparse Shrub Cover
##( 15 )Regularly flooded Shrub and/or Herbaceous Cover
##( 16 )Cultivated and managed areas
##                                  (Examples of sub-classes at reg. level *: 
##                                    (i) terrestrial; (ii) aquatic (=flooded during cultivation),  and under terrestrial:  
##                                    (iii) tree crop & shrubs (perennial),  
##                                    (iv) herbaceous crops (annual), non-irrigated, (v) herbaceous crops (annual), irrigated)
##( 17 )Mosaic: -
##                Cropland / Tree Cover / Other natural vegetation
##( 18 )Mosaic: -
##                Cropland / Shrub or Grass Cover 
##( 19 )Bare Areas
##( 20 )Water Bodies (natural & artificial)
##( 21 )Snow and Ice (natural & artificial)
##( 22 )Artificial surfaces and associated areas
##( 23 )No data

TRANS=[]
TRANS.append(5) #lc0 - NaN
TRANS.append(0) #lc1
TRANS.append(0) #lc2
TRANS.append(0) #lc3
TRANS.append(1) #lc4
TRANS.append(1) #lc5
TRANS.append(0) #lc6
TRANS.append(0) #lc7
TRANS.append(0) #lc8
TRANS.append(0) #lc9
TRANS.append(0) #lc10
TRANS.append(4) #lc11
TRANS.append(4) #lc12
TRANS.append(2) #lc13
TRANS.append(2) #lc14
TRANS.append(2) #lc15
TRANS.append(3) #lc16
TRANS.append(3) #lc17
TRANS.append(3) #lc18
TRANS.append(5) #lc19
TRANS.append(5) #lc20
TRANS.append(5) #lc21
TRANS.append(5) #lc22
TRANS.append(5) #lc23

class globClump:

  def __init__( self, filename ):

    #basic GDAL set up:
    self.filename=filename
    self.dataSet=gdal.Open( filename, gdal.GA_ReadOnly )
    self.data=self.dataSet.GetRasterBand(1)
    self.dataArray=self.data.ReadAsArray()

    #geographic set up:
    self.wkt=self.dataSet.GetProjection()
    self.proj=osr.SpatialReference(  )
    #n.b. the following appears not to work!
    #so instead import the MODIS wkt...
    #self.proj.ImportFromWkt( self.wkt )
    self.proj.ImportFromWkt( MODIS_Wkt )
    self.geoLL=self.proj.CloneGeogCS(  )
    self.transformer=osr.CoordinateTransformation( self.proj, self.geoLL  )

    #coordinates from GLC2000
    self.glcLonMin = -180.004464285700010
    self.glcLatMin = 89.995535666300043
    self.glcLatMax = -56.0133924
    self.glcPixelWidth = 0.0089285714 #in degress
    self.glcPixelWidth = 0.0089285714 #in degress

    GLCfilename = "/glusterfs/phd/users/mn811042/glc2000/Img/glc2000_v1_1.img"

    self.glcDataSet=gdal.Open( GLCfilename, gdal.GA_ReadOnly )
    self.glcData=self.glcDataSet.GetRasterBand(1)
    self.glcDataArray=self.glcData.ReadAsArray()

    transform = self.glcDataSet.GetGeoTransform()
    xOrigin = transform[0]
    yOrigin = transform[3]
    pixelWidth = transform[1]
    pixelHeight = transform[5]
    print 'xOrigin, yOrigin, pixelWidth, pixelHeight' 
    print xOrigin, yOrigin, pixelWidth, pixelHeight
    sys.exit()


  def getLC_fromGLC2000(self, lat, lon):

   x = int( (lon-self.glcLonMin)/self.glcPixelWidth )
   y = int( (self.glcLatMin-lat)/self.glcPixelWidth )


   #read the data point
   lcType = self.glcDataArray[y,x]

   #print 'x,y,lon,lat,lcType'
   #print x,y,lon,lat,lcType 

   return lcType


  def getPointLatLon( self, row, col ):
    """
    Get the lat and lon of a pixel.
    Starts at 0,0.

    x0/y0 = top left corrner in meters
    xs/ys = x and y pixel sizes

    Note xs and ys 2nd and 6th in the argument list.
    """

    (x0,xs,xz,y0,yz,ys)=self.dataSet.GetGeoTransform()


    #pixel coordinates in meters
    pixX = col*xs + x0 + xs/2.
    pixY = y0 + row*ys + ys/2.

    #print (x0,xs,xz,y0,yz,ys), pixX, pixY
    return self.transformer.TransformPoint( pixX, pixY )


  def getLatLonAsciiMap( self, res=0.5 ):

    (Y,X)=np.shape(self.dataArray)

    nPft=6

    outMap=np.zeros([nPft,int(180/float(res)),int(360/float(res))])
    outMapN=np.zeros([nPft,int(180/float(res)),int(360/float(res))])

    #       43200   86400
    #print 'Y=',Y,'X=',X

    #ybox= 43200
    #xbox= 86400

    ybox = 21600
    #xbox = 50000
    xbox = 28287
    ybox_var= 2160
    xbox_var= 2828

    #for x in xrange(X):
    #for x in [43200]:
    for x in xrange(xbox-xbox_var,xbox+xbox_var):
      print >> sys.stderr, x,
      #for y in xrange(Y):
      for y in xrange(ybox-ybox_var,ybox+ybox_var):
        t=g.getPointLatLon( y, x )
        #print x,y,t[0],t[1],self.dataArray[y,x]

        data=self.dataArray[y,x]

        if t[1] > self.glcLatMax:
         lc = self.getLC_fromGLC2000(t[1],t[0])
         pft = TRANS[lc]
        else:
         lc = 23
         pft = TRANS[lc]
        #print 'x,y,lat,lon,ci,lc,pft'
        #print x,y,t[1],t[0],self.dataArray[y,x],lc,pft

        if data > 0.:

          yIndx=int(np.floor((t[1]+90.)/float(res)))
          xIndx=int(np.floor((t[0]+180.)/float(res)))

          #print >> sys.stderr, xIndx, yIndx, data


          outMap[pft,yIndx,xIndx]+=data
          outMapN[pft,yIndx,xIndx]+=1.

    for p in xrange(int(nPft)):
      for y in xrange(int(np.floor((180/float(res))))):
        for x in xrange(int(np.floor((360/float(res))))):
          #print (x,y,outMapN[y,x]),

          if outMapN[p,y,x]>0:
            try:
              print 0.01*outMap[p,y,x]/outMapN[p,y,x],
            except:
              print >> sys.stderr, ">>> ",outMap[p,y,x],outMapN[p,y,x]
              sys.exit()
          else:
            print "0",
        print
      print

if __name__=="__main__":

  filename = "MCI2_red_global_sza0_mask.img"


  g=globClump( filename )


  # map centre
  #print "###",g.getPointLatLon( 21600.0, 43200.0 )
  #print "###",g.getPointLatLon( 0, 43200.0 )
  #print "###",g.getPointLatLon( 0, 0.0 )
  #print "###",g.getPointLatLon( 21600.0, 0.0 )

  g.getLatLonAsciiMap()
```

The thing is that the rescaling processes alone with the first map works fine. It also works fine for higher northern latitudes when I merge the two maps, however, it comes with constant strips of zeros in places where it should be the mean like this example of a limited box over Amazon, but all over the world:

[image]

Comment: Could you describe your methodology with the land cover classes outside of the large code block? This might be easier to achieve with the gdal utilities and resample/warp instead of a python script which iterates over pixels (and thus would be really slow).